# How to avoid white space in FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have file name which have white space in string, so my question is this how can I avoid white space in `ffmpeg` command.

CMD:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00 -t 00:00:01 -accurate_seek -i out out.mp4
-threads 5 -preset ultrafast -codec copy -avoid_negative_ts 1 out.mp4
```

error message :

> out: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotation marks.

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00 -t 00:00:01 -accurate_seek -i "out out.mp4" -threads 5 -preset ultrafast -codec copy -avoid_negative_ts 1 out.mp4
```